# Primeng - Dropdown is marked as dirty in template driven forms and nothing has changed

Tags: angular, forms, primeng

I'm using the framework Angular with [PrimeNG](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng-v15-lts/#/). I had a template driven form and when I inspect, I see that the form is marked as `dirty` because the dropdown.

[image]

Why does this happen? I am not changing the value by hand. The only thing I do when the component is created, it loads the dropdown's options and the value.

*HTML Code*:

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onClickSubmit()" #plcModuleForm="ngForm" id="plcModuleForm">
   <div class="fieldForm dirTipo">
      <label for="dirTipo">{{"programming:addressing_type" | i18next}}*:</label>
      <p-dropdown inputId="dirTipo" [options]="dirTipoList" [(ngModel)]="pmEdited.tipoDireccionamiento" name="tipoDireccionamiento" required [readonly]="true"></p-dropdown>
   </div>
</form>
```

*TS Code*:

```
export class PlcRemoteFormComponent implements OnInit {
 // variables
 constructor(
    private readonly actRoute: ActivatedRoute,
    private service: PlcRemoteService
  )
  this.actRoute.params.subscribe(params => {
      this.pmEdited = new ModulePlc();
      this.service.getPlcRemoteList().subscribe(data => {
         this.dirTipoList = data;
      })
  })
}
```

I can't use `reactive forms`, so this can't be a solution and I need that the form is not marked as `dirty` because in the code I need check that it has this state.